# How to add pagination on facet fields Lucene

Tags: java, pagination, lucene, faceted-search, facet

When I drill down on any facet field, their are large number of brands so now i want to add pagination like 5 brands at a time and below it their will be a pagination for brands. See Attachment
Any suggestions, How to handle this?

Below is code for facets count

```
    DirectoryReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDir);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
    TaxonomyReader taxoReader = new DirectoryTaxonomyReader(taxoDir);

    FacetsCollector fc = new FacetsCollector();
    FacetsCollector.search(searcher, new MatchAllDocsQuery(), 10, fc);
```

[image]